# Virtual Machines Won't Start

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-10

I right click on a virtual machine, click 'Start' and I immediately get

[image]

I just created this one from scratch. I have another virtual machine that has been installed for 6 months now that doesn't work either.

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: vmwp.exe
P2: 10.0.14393.351
P3: 5801a49a
P4: unknown
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 00000000
P7: c0000005
P8: 00007ff83fff046e
P9: 
P10:
```

## Software/Hardware

Hyper-V Manager: 10.0.14393.0

Windows 10 Enterprise: 1607 14393.693

Ram: 11GB free of 16GB

Disk: 213GB free of 476GB

## Things I've Tried

Uninstalling and reinstalling the Hyper-V feature.

`sfc /scannow`

`mdsched.exe` and there were no errors

Comment: Look for defective hardware, probably RAM.

Comment: I see a `c0000005` in there, access denied... Maybe Process Monitor will help you see what access is being denied to. Otherwise, use procdump to capture a memory dump of vmwp.exe when it crashes so we can get a better analysis of the crash. Also, make sure your 100% up to date on hotfixes.

Comment: When I try to procdump vmwp I get the error "Error debugging process:
A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x0000001F, 31)"

Comment: Is there enough RAM available on the host to start it? What version of Hyper-V?

Comment: I've answered all of your questions in my question

Comment: i had this when my raid failed and so the drive where the vhds where stored were not available.

Comment: All my VHD's are available and on the only hard drive.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the host?

Comment: Oh yeah for sure, that was the first thing I tried.